# Jetpack compose scroll listener

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way by which I can log an event when scrolling in a Column? I made it scrollable, saved the scroll state, but I can't find where to call a lambda function given as **param** to composable `onScroll: () -> Unit`

Answer (score 17):

You can observe the `scrollState`:

```
 val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
 Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
)
```

You can check the value of this `scrollState`:

```
if (scrollState.isScrollInProgress){
    println("scrolling")
}
```

In case you need to wait for the scroll is completed, you can use `if` + `DisposableEffect`:

```
if (scrollState.isScrollInProgress) {
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            println("scroll completed")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the DisposableEffect knows that it is for the the scrollState when we give it only Unit as a key?

Comment: @Henning When scroll is finished, DisposableEffect disappears from the composition and gets disposed automatically. Compose is magic!

Answer (score 5):

You can keep listening the state of your lazy list by **collecting** the value like this:

```
val state = rememberLazyListState()

LaunchedEffect(state) {
        snapshotFlow { state.isScrollInProgress }
            .collect { /* here boolean result */ }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wondering how to do this in a `LazyColumn`:

```
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
  object : NestedScrollConnection {
      override suspend fun onPostFling(consumed: Velocity, available: Velocity): Velocity {
          // On scroll ended detection
          println("scroll completed")
          return super.onPostFling(consumed, available)
      }
  }
}
```

and

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a property on scroll state called isScrollInProgress. That one can be used. If isScrollInProgress is true i called my own lambda function `onScroll()`. Works fine.

Comment: Can you write some code to explain what you mean?